# Change style to li JS

Tags: javascript, css

**EDIT:** I edited the post with proper image and updated code.

I have a list of elements (in this case div's with some info from a JSON) that I want to show or hide depeding on the value of a slider control.

I'm trying to loop through the list of elements and ask for the style that the element has, if he ID of said element is the same as the value selected in the silder, than I want that element to be shown and all the rest hidden. This is so far my script:

```
            function myFunction(valor) {
        //alert("Has seleccionado "+valor);
                var elementos = document.getElementsByClassName("inner");
                alert ("Tienes " + elementos.length + " elementos.");
                var i;
                for (i = 1; i < elementos.length; i++) {                        
                    var sty = document.getElementById("age"+i); 
                    alert("age"+i);
                        if (getComputedStyle(sty).getPropertyValue("visibility") == "hidden") { 
                            document.getElementById("age"+valor).style.visibility = "visible";
                        } else {                            
                            document.getElementById("age"+i).style.visibility = "hidden";
                        }

                }
        }
```

**This is how I paint the list, BTW:**

```
      $(window).load(function(){

    $.getJSON('http://xxxxxxxxx0/xxxxxx.json', function(data) {
    var output="<ul class='lista'><div class='outer'>";
    for (var i in data.lbclassic) {         
        output+="<div style='visibility:hidden;' class='inner'id="+"age" + data.lbclassic[i].ageinweeks+">"+"<p>" + data.lbclassic[i].ageinweeks + "--" + data.lbclassic[i].cumul + "--" + data.lbclassic[i].perhh+ "--" + data.lbclassic[i].perhd+ "--" + data.lbclassic[i].eggweightinweek+ "--" + data.lbclassic[i].eggmasscumul1+ "--" + data.lbclassic[i].eggmassinweek+ "--" + data.lbclassic[i].eggmasscumul+"</p></div>";
    }
    output+="</div></ul>";
    document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML=output;
```

});

Also, here's an image of said problem; before I run the script I apply the .elementos class to each compponent in the list so IT HAS A STYLE. However the script will always return the "NO tiene estilo" alert.

[image]

Comment: Ids have to be **unique**, and as there is no `style` attribute in the markup `sty.getAttribute("style")` will return `null` -> "NO tiene estilo"

Comment: They are unique, the image is only a test. Same problem happens either way. What I found out so far is that that style has to be added inline to the local element, not in a stylesheet. Now I'm working from there...

Comment: No, they are not: `<div ... id=age" + data.lbclassic[i].ageinweeks+"><p id=age" + data.lbclassic[i].ageinweeks+">` the `<div>` has the same id as its `<p>` child.

Comment: And as I've already written. `.getAttribute()` returns the value of the attribute if **it is defined in the markup** - `<div style="...">`. If you wan't the values as shown in the screenshot you need the computed values [`.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

Comment: Andreas, in the original test my p has no ID, as I said, that was only a test, it didn't work either way and it was because  I wasn't setting the style inline. I'll try the .getComputedStyle now, thank you.

Comment: Then why don't you post the original code?!

Comment: you have also another mistake `output+="</ul></div>";` it should be `output+="</div></ul>";`

Comment: Thanks Amani, I fixed that. Andreas, I did what you said, however I'm still not able to make it work properly. Can you check again?

Comment: Ok, I re-updated it. The only thing that does't work now is when I get to value 90 (the last one on the list and slider) when I try to go back that last value (90) won't hide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I finally managed to do it:

```
            function myFunction(valor) {
        //alert("Has seleccionado "+valor);
                var elementos = document.getElementsByClassName("inner");
                var i;
                for (i = 1; i < elementos.length+1; i++) {
                        document.getElementById("age"+i).style.visibility = "hidden";
                }
                document.getElementById("age"+valor).style.visibility = "visible";
        }
```